# How to backup database to disk using JPA?

Tags: jpa

Which query to write in JPQL for backing up database on disk? If in JPQL it's not available even native sql query will do.

Also, i would like to bring one issue in front of stackoverflow developers :- This site doesn't properly work in Opera (Opera 9.63). Whenever i write question and click "Post Your question" The button click event doesn't fire at all, may be, the server side event doesn't fire or something. However, no such problem comes in IE and firefox.

Comment: You cannot use the database's native backup tool? It has to be triggered from Java?

Comment: Your issue with Opera should be moved to http://meta.stackoverflow.com btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [named queries](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13189_01/kodo/docs40/full/html/ejb3_overview_query.html#ejb3_overview_query_named).

Comment: what is the link between named queries, which are nothing more than queries, and disk backup ??